# evaluating a regex in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a regex related question; here is a code snippet:

```
rr <- regex("^chapter [\\divxlc]", ignore_case = T)
library(dplyr)
dd <- c("hello there", "Chapter 1", "begining of life", "end of chapter", "Chapter X", "Chapter T", "Chapter 10")

dd_df <- data_frame(line=1:length(dd), text = dd)
# dd_df now looks as follows
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  line text            
 <int> <chr>          
1     1 hello there    
2     2 Chapter 1      
3     3 begining of life
4     4 end of chapter  
5     5 Chapter X      
6     6 Chapter T      
7     7 Chapter 10 (edited)
```

when I evaluate the regex expression against the lines in `dd_df`

```
dd_df %>% mutate(rr = str_detect(text, rr), regexp = "^chapter [\\divxlc]")
```

I get:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4


line text             rr    regexp              
 <int> <chr>            <lgl> <chr>                
1     1 hello there      FALSE "^chapter [\\divxlc]"
2     2 Chapter 1        TRUE  "^chapter [\\divxlc]"
3     3 begining of life FALSE "^chapter [\\divxlc]"
4     4 end of chapter   FALSE "^chapter [\\divxlc]"
5     5 Chapter X        TRUE  "^chapter [\\divxlc]"
6     6 Chapter T        FALSE "^chapter [\\divxlc]"
7     7 Chapter 10       TRUE  "^chapter [\\divxlc]"
```

I cannot figure how lines 2 and 7 are evaluating to `TRUE`?

Comment: I got the answer: "\\d" is escape for \d, so the regex is looking for a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `regex` is defined as : `regex("^chapter [\\divxlc]", ignore_case = T)`

Please note that `ignore_case = T`. Hence, `"^chapter "` will match with `Chapter` in row 2 and 7.

The next part is `[\\divxlc]` -- That means look for either a `digit` (`\\d`) or a character from `i`, `v`, `x`, `l`, or `c`.

Again in row 2 and 7 `Chapter` followed by `1` which matches `\d`. Hence those two rows  (`2 & 7`) and `5` are matched.

None of other rows matches those two condition.